# Python - Making a POST request

Tags: python, django, oauth, youtube, youtube-api

I'm trying to use Youtube apis in my web application by following this guide https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_oauth2#OAuth2_Server_Side_Web_Applications_Flow I've done upto step 3 successfully and got the ** authorization code**.

Now I stuck with making POST request to this url `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token`

I want to make a request like this: (taken from the link I've given above)

```
POST /o/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
Host: accounts.google.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

code=4/ux5gNj-_mIu4DOD_gNZdjX9EtOFf&
client_id=1084945748469-eg34imk572gdhu83gj5p0an9fut6urp5.apps.googleusercontent.com&
client_secret=hDBmMRhz7eJRsM9Z2q1oFBSe&
redirect_uri=http://localhost/oauth2callback&
grant_type=authorization_code
```

I tried something like this:

```
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded code=4/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&client_id=xxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com&client_secret=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&redirect_uri=http://127.0.0.1:8000/information/youtube/&grant_type=authorization_code'}

r = requests.post(url, headers)
```

and I'm getting this error:

```
<Response [411]>
u'<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang=en>\n  <meta charset=utf-8>\n  <meta name=viewport content="initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">\n  <title>Error 411 (Length Required)!!1</title>\n  <style>\n    *{margin:0;padding:0}html,code{font:15px/22px arial,sans-serif}html{background:#fff;color:#222;padding:15px}body{margin:7% auto 0;max-width:390px;min-height:180px;padding:30px 0 15px}* > body{background:url(//www.google.com/images/errors/robot.png) 100% 5px no-repeat;padding-right:205px}p{margin:11px 0 22px;overflow:hidden}ins{color:#777;text-decoration:none}a img{border:0}@media screen and (max-width:772px){body{background:none;margin-top:0;max-width:none;padding-right:0}}\n  </style>\n  <a href=//www.google.com/><img src=//www.google.com/images/errors/logo_sm.gif alt=Google></a>\n  <p><b>411.</b> <ins>That\u2019s an error.</ins>\n  <p>POST requests require a <code>Content-length</code> header.  <ins>That\u2019s all we know.</ins>\n'
```

I know I'm wrong with the post request and I need your guidance on how to make it work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't put the data in the headers. Use the [`data` kwarg](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests) of `.post()` instead. Since a urlencoded POST body is the default there is also no need to specify it via the `headers` argument.

```
data = {
    'code': '4/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    'client_id': 'xxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com',
    'client_secret': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    'redirect_uri': 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/information/youtube/'.
    'grant_type': 'authorization_code'
}
r = requests.post(url, data=data)
```

You can make this code even nicer by letting *requests* deal with the OAuth authentication via the [*requests-oauth*](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests-oauth) extension: https://github.com/maraujop/requests-oauth#readme

Then you can perform your request without handling the OAuth parameters manually.

Comment: I was wondering... how come django doesn't have built-in post requests template tag? Sometimes, we want to change data without a form via a URL and in essence, it feels like a post request...An example is I'm trying to create my own reset password that just resets via a button but to do that, I just send the user to a view, change the password, and redirect them (I didn't want django's e-mail link token process)

Comment: Umm... what? I have no clue what you are trying to do. Sounds like something for a new question though.

Comment: Go here: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/ this is the goods, has more information and examples on the requests python library

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the `data` parameter of `requests.post`

The docs should help: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests